# When I'm trying to run "xterm" in termux, it says "failed to open display : :0". Why so?

Tags: termux

I'm running XServer XSDL. Then tried running xterm in it after `export DISPLAY=:0`. If I do `export DISPLAY=10.94.XXX.XXX:1`, xterm runs fine. I tried to debug it using `strace`. This is the line, which seems to cause the problem `sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`.

I've been discussing this problem on [Xserver/xsdl](https://github.com/pelya/xserver-xsdl/issues/91). I was told it might be an Android permission issue. So I'm searching for help here.

Can anyone help me sort out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some kind of firewall, which is blocking the connection. I was unable to solve this problem. But I found a workaround.

1. Entered a terminal with `root` privilege.
   (E.g: used command `su` in a terminal emulator)
2. Created a 2nd loopback network by `ifconfig`
   (E.g : `ifconfig lo:0 127.0.0.2 netmask 255.0.0.0 up`)
3. Fortunately "XSERVER XSDL" recognized this new network without any complaints (Never thought it could detect such a weird network).
4. At last set my display to a new server from my chroot environment as shown in XSERVER welcome screen.
   `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.2:1 startfluxbox` ( or any xclient program, now everything runs fine)

Note 1: Each time my phone is restarted, I've to create the loopback network again. There might be some .rc files for adding startup scripts on android too. But I never bothered changing them (because I don't restart my phone often).

Note 2: I would really appreciate a true solution though (better if it works without root) because my method can't be applied on a non-rooted phone. So people with this problem but without a rooted phone can't use xserver until someone finds another solution.